# Excel 2010 VBA to copy columns from mutliple worksheets and append in active worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with a VBA. Loop through multiple worksheet in same WorkBook and copy 1 column i.e. col B, and paste/append in the next blank column in the active worksheet.

Thanks,
Adil

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 1):

There are some limitations here but this should get you started.

```
Sub copyColumn()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    'Source worksheet to copy from
    Dim srcwk As Worksheet
    Set scrwk = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

    'Copy range A1:A10 from source to active sheet in next open column
    scrwk.Range("A1:A10").Copy wks.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Sub Move_Column()

CurrWS = ActiveSheet.Name
    For each Sheet in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If Sheet.Name <> CurrWS Then
            NextColumn = Sheets(CurrWS).Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            Sheets(CurrWS).Range(Sheets(CurrWS).Cells(1, NextColumn), Sheets(CurrWS).Cells(100, NextColumn)).Value = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(1, 2), Sheet.Cells(100, 2)).Value
        End if
    Next

End Sub
```